# Python3 - How to iterate with a for loop over the first and the last 10 items in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc....]
```

How do I iterate over the first and the last 10 items in this list?

Thanks

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: What if there are less than 20 items in the list? And if there are less than 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for i in a[:10]:
    print(i)
for i in a[-10:]:
    print(i)
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/G9bwfb)

Comment: Thank you all. I have used this code and added a checking logic for the script to print twice the same thing: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
checked = []
print("first 10")
for i in a[:10]:
    if i in checked:
        continue
    print(i)
    checked.append(i)
print("-----\nlast 10")
for i in a[-10:]:
    if i in checked:
        continue
    print(i)
    checked.append(i)

Answer (score 1):

You can use list slicing:

```
for i in foo[:10] + foo[-10:]:
    print(i)
```

The drawback of this first solution is that if your list has less than 20 elements but more than 10, some elements will be iterated on twice.

---

To avoid that, a slightly more complex version could be:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
for i in lst[:10] + [x for x in lst[-10:] if x not in lst[:10]]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append two subsets of the list, one containing the first 10 elements and the second containing the last 10:

```
for elem in foo[:10] + foo[-10:]:
    # do something
```